# Rails: Turn off error display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I access a post that doesn't exist in my Rails project via the URL `/posts/13`, the browser shows a verbose error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show

Couldn't find Post with ID=13
Rails.root: ...
...
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"13"}
...
```

Is there a way to turn this detailed error display off?

Comment: run a server in production. `rails s -e production`

Comment: I'm already running my project in production via a script hosting website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

- run a server in production `$ rails s -e production`
- remove *ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions* middleware

  `config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions)`
- set `config.consider_all_requests_local       = false` in your environment config

Comment: Okay, just before I try that, could you please let me know the steps if I want to turn the error display back on as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, where do I put `config.middleware.delete(ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions)`?

Comment: inside your environment config file. (config/environemnts/#{environment}.rb) to turn it back just remove the line that removes the middleware or set the consider_all_request_local to true

Comment: Okay, apparently my project website was running in development mode, and when I set `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` in `development.rb`, the error disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad to help. What I suggested is how production environment is set up by default.