# Can't catch ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound with rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Ruby, please bear with me if this is a stupid question, or if I'm not following the best practice.

I'm finding an object in the DB using `find()`, and expect it to throw `RecordNotFound` in case the object of the id does not exist, like this.

```
  begin
    event = Event.find(event_id)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    Rails.logger.debug "Event does not exist, id: " + event_id
    return {
        # return "unauthorized" to avoid testing existence of event id
        # (some redacted codes)
    }
  end
```

But somehow it is not caught (the log in the rescue block is not printed) and the entire program just return internal server error. Here's the stack trace:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Event with 'id'=999):

lib/sync/create_update_event_handler.rb:78:in `handleRequest'
app/controllers/sync_controller.rb:36:in `block in sync'
app/controllers/sync_controller.rb:31:in `each'
app/controllers/sync_controller.rb:31:in `sync'
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (6.4ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (36.6ms)
```

The only thing I can think of is there are two different ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, and I'm catching the wrong one, but I don't know if it is the case or how I can verify it.
What did I do wrong?

======================================

**Update**

The problem is in the rescue block, I was concatenating `event_id` (an integer) to a string.
The `RecordNotFound` exception was indeed caught, but when the type error was thrown in the rescue block, the wrong error message was printed.

Comment: I am not sure about your problem, but these links might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849597/rails-turn-off-error-display    and also, read about `rescue_from` feature of Rails which lets you define templates for particular exceptions, on controller itself.

Comment: Are you sure `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error raises on `event = Event.find(event_id)` line?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky I'm pretty sure because the stack trace shown on the browser highlights that line. It is so weird to me that I explicitly catch that exception but it still causes an internal server error.

Comment: @user3374124 Could you post full action code in your question?

Comment: And on that line `lib/sync/create_update_event_handler.rb:78` there is nothing that raises that error? And what about server log? `Rails.logger.debug` should print in case error got rescued. You might also change `return` to `render` if its controller action

Comment: Can you try catching the error's superclass, `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError`?

Comment: Thanks for spending time on this @MartinZinovsky, that line is `event = Event.find(event_id)`, this function returns an object back to the the sync_controller, and the sync_controller always returns 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the error message is wrong.

The problem is that I was concentating the `event_id` (an integer) to a string.
But somehow Rails prints out the RecordNotFound exception.

The problem is fixed by replacing
`Rails.logger.debug "Event does not exist, id: " + event_id`
with 
`Rails.logger.debug "Event does not exist, id: " + event_id.to_s`

Thanks @lacostenycoder for bringing my attention to the error message.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get an error if you do

```
event = Event.find_by(id: event_id)
```

In this case if the record can't be found by ID it will just `event == nil` be nil.
In this case if the record can't be found by ID it will just `event == nil` be nil.

The code you pasted works fine for me. If you don't see output in the log, check your environment and log level settings INFO, WARN, DEBUG etc.  500 error indicates some kind of controller action raising the error.

see [Set logging levels in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180690/set-logging-levels-in-ruby-on-rails)

To be sure your rescue block is executing try doing something besides log. If you're running a development server you can try :

```
    begin
         event = Event.find(event_id)
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
         msg = "Event does not exist, id: #{event_id.to_s}"
         Rails.logger.debug msg.
         puts msg 
         binding.pry # if you have gem 'pry' in your development gems.
         File.open('test.log', 'w') {|f| f.write msg} #check if this appears in root of your app
         return {
                 # return "unauthorized" to avoid testing existence of event id
                 # (some redacted codes)
         }
     end
```

UPDATE: I changed the string interpolation according to your answer.  You can also call `.to_s` inside interpolation instead of closing quotes and appending.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.
Your suggest brought my attention to the content of the rescue block, where I found the problem
FYI I didn't downvote your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.
Your suggest brought my attention to the content of the rescue block, where I found the problem. The problem is the error message, I was concatenating the `event_id` (integer) to a string.

FYI I didn't downvote your reply.

Answer (score 0):

`@event = Event.find(params[:id])`. you should write instead `params[:id]` .That's the cause of an error.

Comment: Thanks, that's the workaround I was using. But I was trying to figure out what's wrong with my code instead of avoiding the exception.